# Provider and key name in keyGenerator

Tags: android, kotlin, keystore

Suppose that we create an `instance` of `KeyStore` like this :

```
   private val ANDROID_KEYSTORE = "AndroidKeyStore"
   val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
```

**What is the best and secure way for set `ANDROID_KEYSTORE` `String` in code or it does not matter?**

And for generate `paramsBuilder` we use key name like this :

```
 private fun createSecretKey(keyName: String){

      val paramsBuilder= KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName,...)
}
```

**What is the best name for choosing `keyName` that we pass it in `fun` how should we hold on or it does not matter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter how you key track of/store your `keyName`. It is not a security concern. You may as well save it as a constant in your source file.

This is generally called a Keystore alias, like in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#Builder(java.lang.String,%20int)). When you generate a key in the keystore, you will have to specify an alias. You will have to use the same alias to [refer/access](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore#getEntry(java.lang.String,%20java.security.KeyStore.ProtectionParameter)) the key at a later time.

As far as I know, there are two things to remember for aliases:

1. An alias should be unique for each keystore entry.
2. Aliases should not differ only in case. Depending on the implementation the keystore aliases may be case-sensitive/case-insensitive. So to err on the side of caution, do not  use aliases in a KeyStore that only differ in case.